# How to check a checkbox using data fetched from database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a problem retrieving data and using it to check checkboxes in Laravel. I want the checkboxes to be checked based on the records on the database when the edit pages are opened.

**Edit view/blade**

```
@php
$productstatus = json_decode($product-\>status);
@endphp
        
<div>
       <label for="status" class="control-label col-sm-2">Product Status</label>
        @foreach($status as $status)
                <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="{{$status->status}}" @if(in_array($status, $productstatus)) checked @endif> <label>{{$status->status}}</label>
            @endforeach
        </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit(Product $product)
{
    $countries = Country::all();
    $status = Status::all();
    $allStatus = Product::pluck('status')->toArray();
    
    return view('products.edit',
        ['product' => $product, 'countries' => $countries, 'status' => $status, 'allStatus' => $allStatus]);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'qty' => 'required|numeric',
        'price' => 'required|decimal:0,2',
        'category' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'status' => 'nullable',
        'description' => 'nullable'
    ]);

    $product = product::where('id', $id)
        ->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'qty' => $request->qty,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'country' => $request->country,
            'status' => json_encode($request->input('status')),
            'description' => $request->description
        ]);
    
    return redirect(route('product.index'))->with('success', 'Product has been updated Successfully!');
}
```

[I want the tickboxes to be ticked based on the values when the edit page is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Xj0.png)

[Here is the array of strings in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTev6.png)

I tried to change the string into arrays back before comparing it to the values but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view file, you compare an object `$status` with an array `$productstatus`. This will not work as expected. You should compare the `status` property of the `$status` object with the `$productstatus` array.

```php
@php
$productstatus = json_decode($product->status);
@endphp

<div>
    <label for="status" class="control-label col-sm-2">Product Status</label>
    @foreach($status as $status)
        <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="{{$status->status}}" @if(in_array($status->status, $productstatus)) checked @endif> <label>{{$status->status}}</label>
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

In this code, `@if(in_array($status->status, $productstatus)) checked @endif` checks if the `status` property of the `$status` object is in the `$productstatus` array. It adds the `checked` attribute to the checkbox input if it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the given line of code.

Convert this

```
$productstatus = json_decode($product-\>status);
```

To

```
$productstatus = json_decode($product->status);
```

Then this checkbox html

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" 
  value="{{$status->status}}" 
  @if(in_array($status, $productstatus)) checked @endif>
```

To

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" 
 value="{{$status->status}}" 
 @if(in_array($status->status, $productstatus)) checked @endif>
```